# Google Sheet Script For Clear Range Automation When Date is Due

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Need help with Google Sheet onEdit(e) Function. I would like to clear D:I columns when date is due. Here's the project sample link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zgskq85pX30FQKW9w29n0hWMtWa0vPX5wZfM3lc93Pw/edit?usp=sharing

And would be a great help if you can explain the function (or syntax?). Sorry, complete Google Script newbie.

The rows can cleared with a check box:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (sh.getName() !== 'Sheet1' || e.range.columnStart !== 7 || e.range.rowstart < 9 || e.value !== 'FALSE') 
    return;
  e.range.offset(0, -3, 1, 3).clearContent()
}
```

But I wanna do clear range if date is due. Is it possible?

Comment: Too vague. You need to describe more closely how do you mean to work with the sheet. Step by step. Where you put your data. How exactly you do it. When and how script (of function should fires) How the result should look like. Etc.

Comment: Hi,
Sorry if its too vague. Here's what i wanna do with the sheet :

function onEdit(e) {
   var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();
   if (sh.getName() !== 'Sheet1' || e.range.columnStart !== 7 || e.range.rowstart < 9 || e.value !== 'FALSE') return;
   e.range.offset(0, -3, 1, 3).clearContent()
   
}

the rows can cleared with check box, but i wanna do clear range if date is due. Is it possible?

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I've added info from your comment into your question. The task look doable. But `onEdit()` means to run as you edit the sheet. It clears a current row as you click on a check box in the current row. Do you mean that the row should be cleared when user changes date in cell? Or it will run as soon as there are any changes in any cell? And should the script clear only the current row or it should check all dates on the sheet?

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for your reply. The row should be automatically cleared when the date is due. I try to use the script above since I have very limited knowledge of Google Script but it doesn't quite right. Any suggestions?

Comment: *when the date is due* -- how the script should run? It can run manually from Script editor, or via custom menu. It can run automatically when you open the speadsheet. It can run automatically when you change some cells. Could you clarify?

Comment: If possible, it run automatically when the date is due like we do conditional formatting.  But from what i read and my minumum understanding, perhaps the best option is to time-triggered it every minute?

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this:

```
function set_trigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("clear_rows_due_date").timeBased().everyMinutes(1).create();
}

function clear_rows_due_date() {
  var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var time_zone = ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  var today     = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), time_zone, "yyMMdd");
  var sheet     = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var last_row  = sheet.getLastRow();
  var first_row = 9;
  var data      = sheet.getRange('d' + first_row + ':f' + last_row).getValues();

  for (var r in data) {
    if (data[r][2] == '') continue;
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(data[r][2]), time_zone, "yyMMdd");

    if (date < today) {
      var row_index = +r + first_row;
      var a1range = 'd' + row_index + ':f' + row_index;
      sheet.getRange(a1range).clearContent();
    }
  }
}
```

You have to run the first function `set_trigger()` and wait. It will run every minute the second function `clear_rows_due_date` that will clear the cells D, E, F if cell F contains the date older than today.

Comment: Super awesome. It works. its okay if i change your code from "if (date  < today)" to "if (date = today)", right? And if you don't mind, would you please explain what every lines do? honestly i try to learn about the script with my knowledge limitation. Anyway, thank you very much for your help

Comment: `if (date = today` I think there should be `==` (double). I suppose it will clean only rows with current date. As for to explain every line. I don't know. This script is quite simply. It would be much better for you if you google any function you don't understand first, and try to figure it out by yourself. And ask me only if it didn't help. If you can read English there are A LOT of very good examples and lessons you can use for learning. Good luck.